# js document conflicting with D3.js - no d3js tools are working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to experiment with D3.js, however my code only works when contained in  tags in the HTML parent document - and not if I contain my JavaScript in an external JS document (i.e. script.js):

**In index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>D3js Test</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="scripts/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to do something extremely simple

**In script.js**

```
var spaceCircles = [30, 70, 110];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 200)
                                .attr("height", 200);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                      .data(spaceCircles)
                      .enter()
                      .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                   .attr("cx", function (d) { return d; })
                   .attr("cy", function (d) { return d; })
                   .attr("r", 20);
```

Anyone have an idea about what I am missing?

Thanks, 
TG

**EDIT** Thanks to @Carlos487 I did manage to get it to work - but it required referencing jQuery and containing everything in a doc ready command. I feel like this shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: Also to note - I have tried this in both Firefox and Chrome with the same result

Comment: Have you try putting all this code inside a $(document).ready(), you have to add jquery but you will get sure everything is loaded correctly before executing anything

Comment: This did work! - however, adding jQuery as a dependency seems odd - I feel like this is something that should work on its own

Comment: Great @tgunn I'm glad it help, I will put it on an aswer so you can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try putting all this code inside a $(document).ready(), you have to add jquery but you will get sure everything is loaded correctly before executing anything

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `<body>` of the HTML has not yet loaded when you are trying to manipulate it in the external file script.js, which is loaded before the `<body>` already in the `<head>`. Try moving the reference to script.js inside the `<body>` tag, just before the closing `</body>`. Placing Javascript in the end of HTML files is also generally good practice from perfomance point of view.

Comment: True - however, moving the script reference to <body> did not fix the issue.

Comment: That sounds like loading and evaluating the two JS files are not done in synchronous manner. If wrapping with jQuery document.ready works, wrapping with JavaScript built-in window.onload or similar should work too.

Answer (score 1):

here is a non jquery way to run the script (or more accurately, to run the portion of your script that depends on having html elements like `body` existing) after everything else is loaded

```
//script.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myInit);
function myInit(){
  var spaceCircles = [30, 70, 110];
  var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  ...
};
```